# computational-expensive signal reconstruct - a combination problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, oc.optimization-and-control

My problem is:

I have a time series signal (vibration signal), use BSS algorithm (Blind Source Separation, we can regard it as a black box), separate the source signal into 100 components.

Now I want to reconstruct the source signal by linear superposition, which is feasible in theory. But in practice, these components could be reversed, which means that if the correct component is **(1 -1 1 -1)**, what I get maybe **(-1 1 -1 1)**, so I can not reconstruct source signal correctly.

Thus, I have to do exhaustive search:

**step1:**
Suppose all 100 components are not reversed. There is 1 combination. Linear superpose 100 components, then subtract the source signal, check the result equals **(0 0 0 0)** or not (suppose signal length is 4).
If yes, means I reconstruct the source signal correctly and get the 100 all-correct components.
If not, go on to step2;

**step2:**
Suppose 99 components are not reversed, and 1 component is reversed. There are ${100! \over 99!\cdot1!}=100$ combinations. For every combination case, linear superpose 100 components, then subtract the source signal, check the result equals **(0 0 0 0)** or not.
If yes, means I reconstruct the source signal correctly and get the 100 all-correct components.
If not, go on to step3;

...

**step99**

**step100**

As you see, the procedure would be computational-expensive. There are more than **10^29** combinations in 50 reversed and 50 not-revered case.

So, I would appreciate it if anyone know there are some optimized algorithms for the combination problem.